How to encrypt a file with openssl like it’s done by node?
I’m trying to convert a NodeJS script that I’m using to encrypt JSON files to the openssl format, but I can’t find a way to get the exact same result.
Here is the NodeJS script:
const process = require("process")
const crypto = require("crypto")
const fs = require("fs")

const cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-256-cbc", process.argv[3])
const data = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], "utf8")
const buffer = Buffer.concat([
  new Buffer(cipher.update(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), "utf8")),
  new Buffer(cipher.final())
])

fs.writeFileSync(process.argv[4], buffer)

I call this script this way:
node encrypt.js /path/to/file.json "password" /path/to/encrypted/file

FWIW, the decryption script is the following:
const process = require("process");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");

const cipher = crypto.createDecipher("aes-256-cbc", process.argv[3]);
const data = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], "binary");
const buffer = Buffer.concat([
  new Buffer(cipher.update(data, "binary")),
  new Buffer(cipher.final()),
]);

console.log(buffer.toString("utf8"));

I call it this way:
node decrypt.js /path/to/encrypted/file "password" > /path/to/decrypted/file.json

Since I’d like to get rid of Node for this task, I thought that OpenSSL would be a perfect fit. However, I can’t find a way to achieve the exact same result.
Here is what I tried:
# Encryption
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -k "password" -nosalt -in /path/to/file.json -out /path/to/encrypted/file

# Decryption
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -k "password" -nosalt -in /path/to/encrypted/file -out /path/to/decrypted/file.json

When I use the encryption/decryption OpenSSL commands together, they are able to encrypt a file and decrypt it. But, the encrypted content from OpenSSL is not the same as the encrypted content from NodeJS.
Moreover, I cannot decrypt files encrypted by the NodeJS script with the OpenSSL decryption command since I get the following error:
bad decrypt
405735A2AD7F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:

I already spent some time reading posts from SO and other sources, but all provided answer fail to fix the issue.
Might not be relevant, but here are the versions used:

NodeJS: v20.11.1
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024)


In that OpenSSL (or any >= 1.1.0) for enc to match nodejs crypto's "OpenSSL compatible" mode, add -md md5.

Say whaaaaat? That worked like a charm! I spent so much time on this and I’m pretty sure I did try to add this option… But maybe with other options too, I tried so many variants that I’m not even sure! Thank you so much, if you could make this an answer I will accept it as the solution!

The observed discrepancy between the outputs of your JavaScript code and that of the openssl command seems to come down to four major points that I could identify (so far):

An issue with your JavaScript code;
OpenSSL's key derivation function;
The cipher's initialization vector;
What seems to me like an issue with Node's crypto libary.

Addressing the points in order:

By calling the JSON.stringify() function in your program encrypt.js, you are actually changing the data fed to the cipher. Instead, try calling fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]) directly on your file, which will defaults to reading the file's raw binary contents.

In OpenSSL, by default, encryption is not performed with your supplied password directly. Instead the password is first padded with 0 (NULL) bytes to the required size and then run through a key derivation function (such as PBKDF2 or Argon2) to expand and strengthen it. By not supplying OpenSSL with an explicit derivation function, the default PBKDF2 is used. Furthermore, encryption is performed with a hex key. If you want OpenSSL to use your key verbatim (without derivation), you must use the -K parameter and provide a hex value of appropriate size (i.e. for AES: matching in bit size the cipher's strength; in your case 256 bits).

The AES-256-CBC is a blockchain cipher, which means that it uses the previous block's output as part of the input for encrypting the next block. For this reason the algorithm requires a initialization vector (IV) to bootstrap encryption of the first block of data. If not supplied, it is generated from the encryption key. In your JavaScript code, calling crypto.createCipheriv() instead of crypto.createCipher() will allow your to pass in an explicit IV as a third parameter. Similarly, with the openssl command, you may use the -iv parameter for using a specific IV.

Node's crypto.createCipheriv() function throws an error when passed a 256-bit long IV and only seems to work with a 128-bit long IV. This, as far as I understand, seems to be a deviation from the correct implementation of the AES-256-CBC cipher, which should require an IV of the same bit size as the cipher. By contrast, the openssl command returns an error when supplied a 128-bit long IV and works fine with a 256 long IV. This point alone seems to prevent the output of Node's crypto library and that of the openssl command to ever be compatible with the AES-256-CBC cipher until this issue is addressed.


Some (more or less relevant) further reading that you may find interesting:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221964/openssl-1-1-1b-warning-deprecated-key-derivation-used
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132162/what-size-of-initialization-vector-needed-for-aes-256-encryption-in-java
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-enc.html
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector


First of all, thanks for this meticulously detailed answer! For (1), I got rid of the JSON.stringify part but the encrypted contents are still not the same between NodeJS/OpenSSL methods. For (2,3 & 4), the issue is that there are some automated systems which generate these secrets automatically using (kind of) the JS code I provided. I could update all these systems as well as re-encrypt all existing secrets but I would have preferred not going down this road. Plus, (4) may be a pita in such case… Anyway, I’ll take a look at the links you provided!

FWIW, I did try to use the -K option like that: -K "$(echo -n "password" | xxd -p -c64) -iv 0 (-c64 because my password is much more longer than just "password") but it didn’t generate the same output as NodeJS. I also tried a bunch of different IV, with the same results. I’m not even sure if the crypto.createCipher() method uses some kind of default IV. I gave a look at some articles to migrate to crypto.createCipheriv() but they all somehow store the IV in the encrypted content, so if there was a default one with crypto.createCipher(), I would be able to see it (I guess).

#2 openssl enc does not default to PBKDF2, not even in 3.2. Since 1.1.0 it defaults to EVP_BytesToKey with 1 iteration of SHA256; before that it was EVP_BytesToKey with 1 iteration of MD5. Since 1.1.1 it does give a warning this KDF is deprecated; it would be more correct to say 'awful'. #3 openssl enc does derive both the key and IV and nodejs crypto.create{Cipher|Decipher} (without iv) DOES ALMOST EXACTLY WHAT OLD OpenSSL DID: EVP_BytesToKey with 1 iteration of MD5, but no salt, whereas openssl enc has defaulted to salt since 0.9.something.

#4 a cipher doesn't have one bit size. All AES variants have a 128-bit data block; AES-128/192/256 specifies the key size. For CBC the IV is one data block, thus is 128-bits regardless of the key size. But as above both enc-default and nodejs-deprecated derive the key AND the IV, so you don't specify either, only the password which is misleading called a key.

Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for your input. I will review this information and amend my answer accordingly.
